# returning amount of times an integer is displayed in pandas column

Tags: python, count

I'm trying to return the amount of times the log mass of 5.00 is displayed among a number of species,  but the count function is giving me an error. These values are located in a pandas column titled 'log mass'. The column has been separated from the rest of the data frame, so the output looks like this

```
log mass
4.7
4.8
5.0
5.0
5.1
```

> object has no attribute levels

anyone know how to remedy this? Thanks.

```
def count():
        africa = dataframe[dataframe['continent'] == 'AF']
        log_mass = africa['log mass']
        return log_mass.count([5.00])
print(count())
```

Comment: Your indentation is incorrect and I don't think this the whole code!

Comment: Yould you provide some information on what dataframe contains or what it's structure is? Is it just a list of dictionaries?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it, not super elegant however:

```
temp_df = dataframe[dataframe['continent'] == 'AF']['log mass'].value_counts().to_frame()

temp_df[temp_df.index == 5.00]
```